# unable to get input value and attach it to iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with input box, where user will enter a URL, and than this URL gets added as SRC for multiple IFRAMES. but I'm unable to do so. Can anyone tell me whats wrong here and even improvise it.

And is it even possible to manage it using FORM Tag and Submit button?

```js
  var frametest = $('#test-url').val();
  var urlproto = 'http://';
  $('#get-url-btn').click(function() {
    $('.demo-frame').attr('src', urlproto + frametest);
  });
```

```css
.demo-frame {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="url" id="test-url" placeholder="Enter URL">
  <button type="button" id="get-url-btn">Check</button>
</div>
<div class="demo">
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
  <iframe class="demo-frame" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as i see the result from of this code i don't see any problems. urlproto variable is updating the src of the iframes properly. Could you be more specific

Comment: its just adding **http://** in the SRC of IFRAMES, I want any entered URL in Input box gets added along with `http://URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are retrieving a null value of that input text, instead make your js code like this: *you can test it with this url **www.example.com**

```
var urlproto = 'http://';
$('#get-url-btn').click(function () {
    var frametest = $('#test-url').val();
    $('.demo-frame').attr('src', urlproto + frametest);
});
```

However, this might not work always because of `'X-Frame-Options'` to `'SAMEORIGIN'`or `DENY`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/adcmodtu/)

Answer (score 1):

You take the frametest variable too early
Put it inside the click()function

```
  var urlproto = 'http://';
  $('#get-url-btn').click(function() {
    var frametest = $('#test-url').val();
    $('.demo-frame').attr('src', urlproto + frametest);
  });
```